# Can I use scasb on a program's own code?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, att

For code golf I'm trying to use `scasb` to read my program's own source. However, in 32-bit mode with `es:edi` and 64-bit mode `rdi` I always get a segfault, even with `es = 0`. So I would like to know: is this even possible?

Here is some example code. Again note `str` is in `.text`, not `.data`.

```
.section .text
.globl main
main:
        mov     str, %rdi       # load string
        scasb                   # cmp edx, (rdi)  

        ret

str:    .byte 0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05
```

Comment: You want `mov  $str, %rdi` . Without the `$` `str` is being treated as a memory operand so you moved the 8 bytes starting at `str` and placed them in RDI. You wanted to move the address of `str` to _RDI_. The character you want to compare needs to be in _AL_

Comment: @MichaelPetch you're completely correct. I even went through with GDB and somehow missed this. Can you post as answer?